# Import program files into fresh Ubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, ssd

recently I bought an SSD and I want to install Ubuntu 18.10 on it now.

Since I already have an Ubuntu installation, I was wondering if it is possible to copy only my custom/own files to the new installation so I don't have to install/configure everything again.

Comment: You can copy the whole disk if you would want to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wanted to add a comment, but as I don't have enough reputation yet, adding this as an answer.

If you're planning to install and use the same softwares, then you can copy your configurations to the new drive. If you're doing a fresh OS install on your ssd, install the softwares you're using and then overwrite the configs with your current one.

Most of the configs are stored inside `/etc/` and inside your home directory. If you've multi user setup then you may have to copy those configs for other users home directory too.

Configurations for systemwide software or applications are found inside `/etc/` directory, like nginx, mysql, network settings etc. Inside your home directory, you have configs or customisations for softwares like bash (.bashrc), vim (.vimrc) etc. Also steam and other softwares stores a lot of settings and files inside your home directory.

And obviously your documents, pictures and other medias will be inside home directory. And if you had other partitions on the old drive and stored your own files there then you need to copy them too.

Comment: This is definitely an answer (and a good one), not a comment. +1 from me.

Comment: Usually the new drive is going to be bigger than the old drive, so I do exactly as Tuhin suggests: install the new OS, copy my old OS into the new drive (using rsync or similar), then re-install the various applications and _usually_ copy the old settings from my old drive-copy to my new setup. Sometimes software has changed and a direct copy of settings doesn't work. To account for this I tend to keep a text file that contains a long list of all the tweaks I've done to a system, so I can replicate my setup.